# insert is not working as expected while doing partitioning

Tags: postgresql, trigger, partitioning

Created a table with one column and sample values

```
create table t1 ();
alter table t1 add column id_ numeric;
insert into t1 values (generate_series(1,10));
```

And, done partitioning odd numbers in one table and even numbers in one table.

```
create table t1_odd (check (id_%2!=0)) inherits (t1);
create table t1_even (check (id_%2=0)) inherits (t1);

create table t1_r15 (check (id_<6)) inherits (t1);
create table t1_r510 (check (id_>4)) inherits (t1);
```

Call this function while `insert` or `update` anything in table `t1`

```
create or replace function t1_func() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if NEW.id_ % 2 != 0 then
       insert into t1_odd values (NEW.*);
    else
       insert into t1_even values (NEW.*);
    end if;
    return null;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger t1_trig before insert or update on t1 for each row execute procedure t1_func();
```

Call this function while `delete` anything from table `t1`

```
create or replace function t1_rfunc() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if NEW.id_ < 5 then
        insert into t1_r15 values (NEW.*);
    else
        insert into t1_r510 values (NEW.*);
    end if;
    return null;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger t1_rtrig before delete on t1 for each row execute procedure t1_rfunc();
```

It works fine for `insert`, and If i tried to `update`, getting some error

```
update t1 set id_ = id_ + 1;
```

gives

```
ERROR: new row for relation "t1_odd" violates check constraint "t1_odd_id__check"
SQL state: 23514
Detail: Failing row contains (2).
```

and while doing `delete` nothing gets inserted into `t1_r15` or `t1_r510` (data got removed from `t1`).

Am I missing anything?

(Using Postgresql 9.5)

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the checks you use for your child tables, it is obvious why such an `UPDATE` runs into problems.  Adding one to `id_` changes it from even to odd or back - the new row does not match the check anymore.

The first trigger is not enough to circumvent this as it does not remove the old row from the child table.  You need a mechanism that does exactly this - delete the old row version and readd the new to either `t1` or the matching child.  This trigger has to be defined on `t1_odd` and `t2_even`.